# Python: How can I improve the efficiency of my function to check if a number is a prime

Tags: python, arrays, performance, global-variables

For school I am required to create a function (not stolen from a module (i.e. Sympy)) that checks if a number is a prime. The challenge for me though is that I need to check quite large numbers.

I wrote the piece of code below but my VS Code is constantly crashing unexpectedly. The function seems to be very slow. (And yes, I know using "global" is bad practice)

```
def is_divisible(num, divisor_list):
    
    for n in divisor_list:
        if (num % n == 0) and not (n == num):
            return True
    return False

#base prime
primes = [2]
last = primes[-1]

def is_prime(number):
    global primes
    start = (primes[-1] // 2 * 2) + 1 #to get a uneven starting point

    #getting exceptions out of the way
    if number <= 1: 
        return False
    if number == 2:
        return True

    for i in range(start, math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)) + 1, 2):
        if (not is_divisible(i, primes)) and (not i == primes[-1]):
            primes.append(i)
            print(primes)
  
    return not is_divisible(number, primes)
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Not really on topic, but you can remove `global primes`. You would need that when *reassigning* the name `primes` inside the function - but your code doesn't do that, rather it *mutates* the object that the name refers to.

Comment: `is_prime()` only returns false when num <= 1.  In every other case it returns true.  Surely this is a mistake?

Comment: I don't see how the `primes` list increases efficiency at all, since you _don't actually check if `num` is in that list_...

Comment: In the `range()` loop, if `is_divisible()` returns true, the function ought to return false immediately.  but it doesn't -- it just keeps counting up.  this is one big reason why the code is slow.  And the function could return false immediately for any even number greater than two, but it doesn't.

Comment: '...check quite large numbers' How large, in what time? nokia's answer is probably sufficient for your school work, but his answer is based on trial division which is a slow algorithm for a primality test of large numbers. You can use other algorithms which work much faster for 'larger' numbers. There's even the AKS polynomial time primality test, but it's complicated to implement. There's the statement that for odd n, if for any x in [2,n-1], x^((n-1)/2) != +-1 mod n then n is not prime, which can often prove non-primality quickly, but some numbers which are not prime will always give +-1.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have a nested loop, and I don't see a reason for that at all. It has time efficiency of **O(n*m)**.

In addition in your first loop you don't need to check all numbers until the number itself.

A better approach would be to work by the square root of the number:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num <= 1 or num % 2 == 0:
        return False

    i = 3
    while i*i <= num:
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
        i+=2
    return True
```

Every number beyond the square root will need a smaller number (than the root) in order for the result to be `num`. If `num` is not divisible by any smaller number than its root, no number beyond that root could divide that number.

This approach has time efficiency of **O(sqrt(n) / 2)**

Comment: i've improved the efficiency myseldf now! See edited post

Answer (score 1):

One of the best algorithms for checking primes, is the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

It cam be implemented in Python as follows:

```
def isprime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    if x == 2 or x == 3:
        return True
    if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        return False
    if (x - 1) % 6 != 0 and (x + 1) % 6 != 0:
        return False
    i = 5
    while i * i <= x:
        if x % i == 0 or x % (i + 2) == 0:
            return False
        i += 6
    return True
```

This has time efficiency of **O(n log log n),**